# What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion

I get the following information when I tried to ask a new question:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

I've never seen such information in other SE forums before. It is totally acceptable to get "bad" questions closed. BUT, what did I do so wrong that I would **be in danger of being blocked from asking any more**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Huh... that's weird. This is an automated [system notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234042), not something that the users or moderators of this site have a say in.

I looked through your posts and I can't see any reason why you should have received this notice. You only have one down voted question that was self deleted and one that was closed as a duplicate (which is fine, IMO). All your other questions have been well received.

My guess is that the algorithm was trigger happy or that this is an edge case... Unfortunately, I don't think I can do anything about it or offer any advice on how to avoid a ban when you're already asking acceptable & well formatted questions. The only thing I can perhaps say is that if you do actually end up getting automatically banned by system and if your questions continue to be mostly well received like it is now, then please ping one of us in chat and we'll try to get the block removed by the SE team.

Comment: Wait! Some of your past automated messages have not used correct grammar, and you're in danger of being shunned by polite society. (I refer to "well-received", which should be written without the hyphen in the postpositive position.) It's ironic that meta.SE questions asking about this message have received such extremely negative responses.